# Restoring 2D properties from 1D data

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose we have a set of points on a 2D-plane and for all points a condition holds:
$ x_i^2 + y_i^2 = C $
, where C is a constant.

Then, we "fold" this 2D set to 1D with following function and obtain a new set of values: $P_i = x_i + ny_i$, where $n = const$ and $n \geq max \{x_i, y_i\} \forall i$.

The question is: is it possible to show that initial condition holds (show the existence of C? don't care abut the value) only having a set of P values and **without** knowing n (ofc, when n is known, the task is trivial).

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The $P$-values are the orthogonal projection of the original data to the line $\{t(1,n) : t\in\mathbb{R}\}$, hence using these values one cannot distinguish between points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ such that $(x_1-x_2,y_1-y_2)$ is perpendicular to $(1,n)$. Or in other words: take a data set that lies on a circle $x^2+y^2=C$ and add to each data point a vector perpendicular to $(1,n)$, then the $P$-values of the two data sets are equal, but the latter typically needs not be a subset of some circle having $(0,0)$ as its center.

Comment: Are there any type of projections (1D) that would allow proving this condition?

Comment: The argument works for any linear projection -- so "no" in this case. But you can use non-linear projections, for example you could define $P_i:=x_i^2+y_i^2$. Then you can see whether the data are lying on a circle just because the $P_i$ are all equal in that case. Looks hillarious, but even if you have a bit of noise on the data, it gives you a criterion showing that the data lie near a circle.